# nc command doesn´t work in crontab

Tags: bash

Can you please help me with this problem ?

When I issue a /bin/echo "<150>SAMBA" | /usr/bin/nc 142.17.69.11 -u 514 -w 1
in the line command my Syslog server receives the message, but when I put the script´s path in
the crontab it doesn´t receives the message...

```
crontab -l

SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home:/home/bin
*/3 * * * * /home/a1 > /dev/null 2>&1

pwd
/home

more a1

#!/bin/bash
/bin/echo "<150>SAMBA" | /usr/bin/nc 142.17.69.11 -u 514 -w 1
```

Comment: Did you try redirecting the output and stderr of the command to a file to see if you get any kinds of errors?  Also, are you sure that a1 is executable?  Can you run `/home/a1` and have it work as expected from the shell?

Comment: Also, is that spacing accurate?  The `more a1` makes it look like the shebang is on the second line, which would not work.

Comment: The script works fine in the line command - I did a chmod 755 a1 against the script.

Comment: I did this: */3 * * * * /home/a1 >> /home/a1.log , but the log file isn´t create !

Comment: Check email if cron sent you some error output - maybe it was not allowed to create the logfile?

Comment: My  conclusion is: the problem is in the crontab. Is there any way to fix crontab ?

Comment: Here's the obvious question.  Are you sure your cron daemon is running?

Comment: I issued this command and crond is running:
$ ps -ef | grep -i cron
root      2441     1  0  2015 ?        00:08:36 crond